# solve equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation

I am trying to solve the equation:
1000^x = 0.5* 512^x + 0.5* 1728^x
I wonder why the following code does not work.

```
syms x
eqn = (power(1000,x) == 0.5* power(512,x) + 0.5* power(1728,x));
solve(eqn, x)
```

Matlab gives me the x=0 solution, however, I am expecting the 1/3 one.
Is there any way that I can constrain the answer.

Comment: @David Wolframalpha tells that there are two solutions. Second one is x = 1/3

Comment: @Cheery yep you are right

Comment: Does not work means no solution or not correct solution? include the output also help to debug

Comment: I believe Matlab isn't picking up the solution since when x = 1/3, `1000^(1/3) - 512^(1/3)/2 - 1728^(1/3)/2 = -8.8818e^-16` which isn't quite zero to Matlab

Comment: Maybe try dividing by 2 (which is exact) instead of multiplying by 0.5 (which involves floating-point numbers).

Comment: Thank you all for the answer! It still gives only the x=0 answer dividing by 2.